Proving the transitivity of proofs
Here is the theory:
Require Import List.
Require Import Coq.Program.Equality.
Import ListNotations.

(* Symbols of L theory *)
Parameter atom : Set.

Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Notation "-, F" := (f_not F) (at level 75, right associativity).
Notation "F ~> G" := (f_imp F G) (at level 95, right associativity).

Inductive axiom : formula -> Prop :=
  | A1: forall A B, axiom (A ~> B ~> A)
  | A2: forall A B C, axiom ( (A ~> B ~> C) ~> (A ~> B) ~> (A ~> C) )
  | A3: forall A B, axiom ((-, B ~> -, A) ~> ((-, B ~> A) ~> B)).

Reserved Notation "Γ |-- l" (at level 98, right associativity).
Inductive proof_chain (Γ : list formula) : list formula -> Prop :=
  | pc_nil : Γ |-- []
  | pc_axiom : forall (A : formula) l, axiom A -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
  | pc_in : forall (A : formula) (l : list formula), In A Γ -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
  | pc_MP : forall (A B :formula) (l : list formula), In B l -> In (B ~> A) l -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
where "Γ |-- l" := (proof_chain Γ l).

Reserved Notation "Γ |- A" (at level 98, right associativity).
Inductive proof Γ A : Prop :=
  | proof_intro : forall l, Γ |-- (A :: l) -> Γ |- A
where "Γ |- A" := (proof Γ A).

Lemma proof_chain_initial : forall Γ A l, Γ |-- (A :: l) -> Γ |-- l.
Proof.
intros.
inversion H.
- exact H3.
- exact H3.
- exact H4.
Qed.

(* proof skipped *)
Lemma superset_proof: forall (Γ: list formula),
    forall (Δ: list formula), (forall A, In A Δ -> In A Γ) -> Γ |-- Δ.
Proof.
    admit.
Admitted.

(* proof skipped *)
Lemma concat_proofs : forall Γ l1 l2,
  Γ |-- l1 -> Γ |-- l2 -> Γ |-- (l1 ++ l2).
    admit.
Admitted.

Theorem pc_transitivity: forall (Γ l m : list formula), Γ |-- l -> l |-- m -> Γ |-- m ++ l.
Proof.
  intros Γ l m H1 H2.
  induction m as [| a m' IHm].
  - simpl. exact H1.
  - simpl.
    apply proof_chain_initial in H2 as H3.
    apply IHm in H3.

Unfortunately, I am unable to prove pc_transitivity, stuck here:
1 subgoal (ID 101)
  
  Γ, l : list formula
  a : formula
  m' : list formula
  H1 : Γ |-- l
  H2 : l |-- a :: m'
  H3 : Γ |-- m' ++ l
  IHm : l |-- m' -> Γ |-- m' ++ l
  ============================
  Γ |-- a :: m' ++ l

Definition of the terms "consequence" and "proof"  from Mendelsons book:

A well-formed formula C is said to be a consequence in S of a set Γ of
well-formed formula if and only if there is a sequence B_1, …, B_k of
well-formed formulas such that C is B_k and, for each i, either B_i is
an axiom or B_i is in Γ, or B_i is a direct consequence by some rule
of inference of some of the preceding wfs in the sequence.
Such a sequence is called a proof (or deduction) of C from Γ.
The members of Γ are called the hypotheses or premisses of the proof.
We use Γ ⊢ C as an abbreviation for "C is a consequence of Γ".


Allow me to comment on your formal system. I understand that you're following a particular book and want to stay close to it, but you are suffering consequences. What looks elegant on paper need not be the best way to formalize. Your use of lists, in particular, is creating complications that you are unable to overcome. A more direct encoding of a proof system that avoids using lists would make your life easier.

@AndrejBauer I added the definition from the book. I noticed the term "of a set Γ". List is an ordered set, which requires more work from us. But this is the definition for Γ |- A, Γ |-- l was created as a helper relation to define Γ |- A.

Experience shows that formalization quite often requires modifications that may seem irrelevant or even suspicious from the point of view of informal mathematics, but are in fact quite useful. In almost all such cases the mathematical content under scrutiny is improved. I would venture to say that we have such a situation at hand.
You are working with a relation Γ |-- l whose intuitive meaning is: the list of formulas Γ entails all formulas in the list l. Why are we using lists? Probably because they appear in some book somewhere. But as soon as we start formalizing |--, we notice that most of the effort is spent on formalizing trivial facts about lists (that got swept under the rug in the book). At this point we should stop and think: is there a better way?
In the present case, we can observe that the order of the formulas in Γ is immaterial, and so is the fact that a formula may be listed several times. Therefore, we should replace the list Γ of assumptions with a set Γ of assumptions. And we have no use for assuming that Γ finite, so we don't.
What about the list l? It's supposed to record a derivation, represented as a list of formulas. Here the list order is used to express how each step depends on previous ones. We could equally well express such dependence by building a derivation tree, and Coq excels at that sort of thing. Then, instead of having an auxiliary notion Γ |-- l stating “l is a derivation from Γ” (of the head element of l) we will just directly define Γ ⊢ A as the type of derivation trees whose conclusion is A.
Let me remark that there are also some advantages to representing derivations as lists of formulas, but for the purposes of the present exercise they do not seem very relevant. (One such advantage is sharing of common subderivations.)
I include below the resulting code. I made some technical improvements, such as folding axioms into the entailment relation. It takes 170 lines of Coq code to define the formal system, prove admissibility of weakening and of the cut rule, and I threw in the deduction theorem for good measure.
(* A formalization of a classical propositional calculus a la user4035,
   with the following modifications:

   1) We use a set of assumptions rather than a list of assumptions.
   2) We use derivation trees to represent proofs instead of lists of formulas.

   Proofs-as-lists are used in Hilbert-style systems, whereas
   derivation trees are more common in natural-deduction style rules.
   The present formalization is a bit of a mix: the axioms and rules
   are those of a Hulbert-style system, but derivations are not linearized
   into lists. I think it is fair to still call this a mostly-Hilbert-style
   system.
*)

(* Atomic proposition. *)
Parameter atom : Set.

(* We assume atomic propositions form a set with decidable equality. *)
Parameter atom_eq : forall (a b : atom), {a = b} + {a <> b}.

(* Propositional formulas *)
Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Notation "- F" := (f_not F) (at level 35, right associativity).
Notation "F ~> G" := (f_imp F G) (at level 95, right associativity).

(* Equality of formulas is decidable. *)
Lemma formula_eq (A B : formula) : {A = B} + {A <> B}.
Proof.
  decide equality.
  now apply atom_eq.
Qed.

(* Instead of working with lists of assumptions we shall work with
   sets of assumptions. A set of formulas can be represented by its
   characteristic map formula -> Prop. *)

(* Element-hood relation between a formula and a set of formulas. *)
Definition elem (A : formula) (Γ : formula -> Prop) := Γ A.
Infix "∈" := elem (at level 50).

(* The empty context. *)
Definition empty : formula -> Prop := fun _ => False.

(* The union of two sets of formulas. *)
Definition union (Γ Δ : formula -> Prop) A := A ∈ Γ \/ A ∈ Δ.
Infix "∪" := union (at level 61, left associativity).

(* The subset relation between sets of formulas. *)
Definition subset (Γ Δ : formula -> Prop) :=
  forall A, A ∈ Γ -> A ∈ Δ.
Infix "⊆" := subset (at level 71).

(* We now come to main definitions. We first define a type
   Γ |- A whose elements are derivations of formula A
   from assumptions Γ. These are presented as derivation trees,
   rather than more traditional lists.

   Note the difference between declaring that Γ |- A
   is a Prop vs. a Type:

   - if Γ |- A is a Prop, then it is expresses *provability*
   - if Γ |- A is a Type, then it expresses *proof derivations*

   The practical difference is this: if Γ |- A is a Type, then
   its element is a derivation tree which can be freely inspected
   and used; but if Γ |- A is a Prop, then its elements are
   (abstract) witnesses of provability that can only be expected
   for the purpose of constructing an element of Prop.
 *)
Reserved Notation "Γ |- A" (at level 98).
Inductive entails (Γ : formula -> Prop) : formula -> Type :=
  | hypo : forall A, A ∈ Γ -> Γ |- A (* every hypothesis is provable *)
  | axiom1 : forall A B , Γ |- A ~> B ~> A
  | axiom2 : forall A B C, Γ |- (A ~> B ~> C) ~> (A ~> B) ~> (A ~> C)
  | axiom3 : forall A B, Γ |- (- B ~> - A) ~> (- B ~> A) ~> B
  | mp : forall A B, Γ |- B -> Γ |- B ~> A -> Γ |- A (* modus ponens *)
where "Γ |- A" := (entails Γ A).

(* It is convenient to make some parameters implicit. *)
Arguments axiom1 {_} _ _.
Arguments axiom2 {_} _ _ _.
Arguments axiom3 {_} _ _.
Arguments mp {_} {_} (_).


(* Here are some basic observation about |-. *)

Lemma imply_self Γ A : Γ |- A ~> A.
Proof.
  apply (mp (A ~> A ~> A)).
  - apply axiom1.
  - apply (mp ((A ~> (A ~> A) ~> A))).
    + apply axiom1.
    + apply axiom2.
Defined.

(* We can inspect proofs by telling Coq to compute the normal form.
   For example, here is how we can see the proof constructed in
   the previous lemma. *)
Eval compute in (fun A => (imply_self empty A)).
(* output:
     = fun A : formula =>
       mp (A ~> A ~> A)
          (axiom1 A A)
          (mp (A ~> (A ~> A) ~> A)
              (axiom1 A (A ~> A))
              (axiom2 A (A ~> A) A))
     : forall A : formula, empty |- A ~> A
*)

(* Weakening: having more hypotheses does not hurt. *)
Theorem weaken Γ Δ A : Γ ⊆ Δ -> Γ |- A -> Δ |- A.
Proof.
  intros S H.
  induction H as [B ?|?|?|?|C D K L IH1 IH2].
  - now apply hypo, S.
  - apply axiom1.
  - apply axiom2.
  - apply axiom3.
  - now apply mp with (B := D).
Qed.

(* "extend Γ A" is the set Γ ∪ {A}. *)
Definition extend Γ A := fun B => B ∈ Γ \/ A = B.

(* The cut rule is admissible. *)
Theorem CutRule A {Γ B} : Γ |- A -> extend Γ A  |- B -> Γ |- B.
Proof.
  intros H G.
  induction G as [B L|?|?|?|?].
  - destruct (formula_eq A B) as [[]|N].
    + assumption.
    + apply hypo.
      now destruct L as [|].
  - apply axiom1.
  - apply axiom2.
  - apply axiom3.
  - now apply (mp B).
Qed.

(* We need this lemma in the deduction theorem. *)
Lemma drop_antecedent Γ A B : Γ |- B -> Γ |- A ~> B.
Proof.
  intro H.
  apply (mp B).
  - assumption.
  - apply axiom1.
Qed.

(* We conclude with the proof of the deduction theorem, just to show
   that it is quite painless to formalize. *)
Theorem deduction {Γ A B} : extend Γ A |- B -> Γ |- A ~> B.
Proof.
  intro H.
  induction H as [B G|?|?|?|C].
  - destruct (formula_eq A B) as [[]|N].
    + apply imply_self.
    + apply mp with (B := B).
      * apply hypo.
        now destruct G as [|].
      * apply axiom1.
  - apply drop_antecedent.
    apply axiom1.
  - apply drop_antecedent.
    apply axiom2.
  - apply drop_antecedent.
    apply axiom3.
  - apply (mp (A ~> B)).
    + assumption.
    + apply (mp (A ~> B ~> C)).
      * assumption.
      * apply axiom2.
Qed.


"we can observe that the order of the formulas in the lists is immaterial" - the order of formulas is immaterial in Γ as it is a set by definition, but it is important in l (l must be an ordered sequence). Look at the definition: "B_i is a direct consequence by some rule of inference of some of the preceding wfs in the sequence".

Ah, sorry that went past me, I think I got confused by nitation. It's a Hilbert-style proof system where proofs are lists of formulas. My formalization of |- encodes proofs, except that it uses trees instead of lists. (Only a single change is required, it should map into Type rather than Prop, so that we can desttruct the derivation trees.) Is that good enough for your purposes? Hilbert-style proof systems are much less structural, and while they do have some advantages, they certainly don't bring any that I am aware of to formalization.

For example, you could prove a lemma that shows that having a proof tree is equivalent to having a list of steps (traverse the tree to get the list), after which it won't matter wich version we're using. There is one important difference: unfolding a list into a tree may cause an exponential blowup.

"Only a single change is required, it should map into Type rather than Prop, so that we can desttruct the derivation trees." - can you explain this a little more about this in your answer? And give an example of such a proof?

"Hilbert-style proof systems are much less structural" - you don't have a sequence of formulas in your definition of a proof. All the formulas are inside the set Γ. How is the sequence of formulas built in your case. How is your proof system called?

"I do not quite understand why user4035 wants this, but here is the next main definition, namely a relation Γ |-- Δ" - it is not mine, and it is not from the book. It was a helper relation created in this answer by the user Feryll to formalize the definition of Γ |- A (A is a consequence of Γ) from the book that involves a sequence of formulas.

Thanks for making the comments, they help me understand what you're looking for. I have updated the answer to better address your concerns. Let me know if there's anything else I can help with.

I got an error: Error: The reference empty was not found in the current environment.. What is empty? I even tried with js coq: the same result.

Strange, it works for me. Perhaps you copied an intermediate version, when I was editing the code? The definition of empty is on line 46.

You need to inspect the proof of a given by H2. The difficult case is the one where a is in l. You may want to write m' ++ l as l1 ++ a :: l2 and prove a lemma that allows you to get rid of l1 (i.e. strengthen proof_chain_initial to cover the case of concatenations). Then, inspecting the proof of Γ |-- a :: l2 will be sufficient to conclude.
